# While executing UITests one of the secondary threads stops?

Tags: ios, multithreading, xcode-ui-testing

I wonder what is causing stop of secondary thread while UITesting. 
That crash doesn't stop application.

[image]

After all, test finishes with error:

> UI Testing Failure - failed to get snapshot within 15.0s

**Do you have any idea what causes the problem?**